# Facebook omniauth: Ensure unique username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have an app with user authentication with devise + omniauth.
In my User model I want to ensure that the user.name is unique, so that there are no duplicate usernames in my app.

After looking around I came up with the following code:

**User.rb**

```
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 6, maximum: 30}

  def ensure_username_uniqueness
    uniqname = (self.name).dup     
    num = 1
    until(User.find_by(name: uniqname).nil?) do ## returns true, should be false ##
      uniqname = self.name+"-#{num}"    
      num += 1
    end    
    self.name = uniqname      
  end  

  private  

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid        
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name[0..29].downcase.gsub(" ", "-")
      user.ensure_username_uniqueness           
      user.remote_avatar_url = auth.info.image
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
  end
```

When I test Facebook registration with a name that already exists in the database, I get redirected to the sign up page (meaning sign up failed).

I set a binding.pry and noticed that the 'until' loop doesn't get executed since it returns true (even though the name already exists). I can't seem to understand why the loop does not get executed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're missed `do` in the end of `until`

```
until(User.find_by(name: uniqname).nil?) do
```

Comment: You should understand block for `first_or_create ` will be called on new user, not for first.

Comment: yes, I understand. I created one devise user with a unique name e.g. "mock-name" and then tried to sign in with a different user using facebook and omniauth that has the same name. the result was I got redirected to the sign up page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that the User model has already been "scoped" by previous actions in Devise, to only the new user being created. So by the time your ensure_username_uniqueness() method gets called, the `User.find_by()` isn't searching the whole database. Instead Devise has added additional clause(s) that filter the results

A quick fix to get your code working would be to user `User.unscoped` or `User.default_scoped`, so that your query will break out of the current scope and search *all* users:

```
  def ensure_username_uniqueness
    uniqname = (self.name).dup     
    num = 1
    until(User.unscoped.find_by(name: uniqname).nil?) do
      uniqname = self.name+"-#{num}"    
      num += 1
    end    
    self.name = uniqname      
  end
```